# PC keeps changing boot order automatically (Windows/Linux dualboot)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bios, multi-boot

I have a Gigabyte X570 Aorus Pro mainboard, and in the BIOS settings I set the first boot drive to my 250GB SSD which has Windows 10 installed, and the second boot drive to my 500GB SSD which has Ubuntu 22.04 installed.

When I turn on the machine, of course Windows 10 will be booted. To get into Ubuntu, I manually press F12 upon boot, which opens the boot menu (which, to my confusing, shows the Ubuntu disk as first entry), where I pick the Ubuntu disk to boot ubuntu.
When I now restart the PC again from within Ubuntu, Windows 10 will boot again, as expected.

Now the problem is, that when I repeatedly boot into Ubuntu by pressing F12 and selecting the Ubuntu disk (e.g. I install upgrades in Ubuntu and need to reboot), the boot order somehow gets changed, and when I reboot and dont interfere with F12, Ubuntu will be booted instead of Windows 10.

So it is like as if the system "remembers" that I manually booted into Ubuntu a couple of times and decides to change the boot order. I have no clue why this happens, or which setting is responsible for this behaviour.

How can I make the PC do what I set it up to do, and avoid the automatic change of settings which I don't want?

Comment: The update is obviously updating or modifying your EFI entry, that is at least the why, how you prevent that is slightly more complicated

Comment: Have you disabled Fast Boot in Windows?

Comment: I guess you could hook into GRUB update and change boot order using `efibootmgr`? Probably not the cleanest way of doing this, but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this is happening, but I can suggest an alternative.
You have to set the drive with ubuntu as your first boot option and change boot order inside grub to set windows as the default boot option. You can do that using grub customizer. `sudo apt install grub-customizer`. Once this is installed you can open grub-customizer and change the boot order and set windows as the first boot option. You can find full tutorial on how to Change Boot Order in Windows Linux Dual Boot with Grub Customizer [here](https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/).

By doing this you won't have to deal with the bios boot menu and still will boot windows by default and when you want to boot to ubuntu you can simply choose it inside grub itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Did this help ?